# Using <apex:outputField> incorrectly

Tags: apex, visualforce, outputfield

Firstly sorry I am a total apex and VF noob. I created a controller that makes a SOQL query and I would like it displayed on a VF page. Controller saves fine but the VF page complains that I'm using the  incorrectly.

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page Controller="initialMeeting">
  <apex:pageBlock title="Initial Meetings">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!finalList}" var="Meetings">
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!finalList.AccountId}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Subject</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!finalList.Subject}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Date</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!finalList.ActivityDate}"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class initialMeeting {
    public List<Event> finalList {get;set;}
    public initialMeeting() {
        List<Account> retrievedAccounts = [SELECT ID 
                                    FROM Account 
                                    WHERE Status__c = 'Active Prospect'];

        Set<String> evt = new Set<String>();
        for (Account accts : retrievedAccounts) {
            evt.add(accts.ID);
        }

        List<Event> finalList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Subject, ActivityDate 
                            FROM Event 
                            WHERE type='Meeting' 
                            AND AccountId IN :retrievedAccounts];
    }
    public List<Event> getUsersEvents() {
        return finalList;
    }

}
```

Thank you so much in advance for all your help!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Meeting as the merge field as it is an iterator individual variable

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!finalList}" var="Meeting">
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Meeting.AccountId}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Subject</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Meeting.Subject}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Date</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Meeting.ActivityDate}"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Also since you already defined list ,you need not create a local variable with same name as public getter

```
public with sharing class initialMeeting {
public List<Event> finalList {get;set;}
public initialMeeting() {
    List<Account> retrievedAccounts = [SELECT ID 
                                FROM Account 
                                WHERE Status__c = 'Active Prospect'];

    Set<String> evt = new Set<String>();
    for (Account accts : retrievedAccounts) {
        evt.add(accts.ID);
    }
    finalList = new List<Event> ();
    finalList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Subject, ActivityDate 
                        FROM Event 
                        WHERE type='Meeting' 
                        AND AccountId IN :retrievedAccounts];
}
public List<Event> getUsersEvents() {
    return finalList;
}

}
```

You can also use your getter in the page getUserEvents() as {!UserEvents} in your pageblock value .

Answer (score 1):

Your class could be way simpler:

```
public with sharing class initialMeeting {
public List<Event> finalList {
    get {return [SELECT Id, AccountId, Subject, ActivityDate 
                        FROM Event 
                        WHERE type='Meeting' 
                        AND AccountId IN 
                            (select id FROM Account 
                                WHERE Status__c = 'Active Prospect')];
        }
    private set;
}
```

or even simpler

```
public with sharing class initialMeeting {
  public List<Event> getFinalList()  {
    return [SELECT Id, AccountId, Subject, ActivityDate 
                        FROM Event 
                        WHERE type='Meeting' 
                        AND AccountId IN 
                            (select id FROM Account 
                                WHERE Status__c = 'Active Prospect')];
  }
}
```

and then use the VF page as Mohith laid out

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!finalList}" var="Meeting">
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Meeting.AccountId}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Subject</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Meeting.Subject}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Date</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Meeting.ActivityDate}"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```